# Targeting specific checkbox with tag in listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, tags

In my app I have a list with rows, each containing an image, text, and a checkbox. I overrode the getView method of my simpleadapter to include a tag for each checkbox based on its position in the row (code is here http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/YME ... bs and bs1 are booleans). That way I could tell which checkbox was being changed when onCheckedChanged was invoked. However, I need to set the state of individual checkboxes manually. For example, set the state of the checkbox with tag "3" (the checkbox on row 3) to "true."

Any help on this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace your approach with an array of booleans. For example, if you have 15 elements in array, you can create a boolean[15], and change state of different positions when user clicks a checkbox, as well as set the initial state in the beginning.

Not a perfect example, but I hope you'll get the idea:

```
public class YourActivity extends Activity {

protected boolean[] checkStates;

protected void onCreate(android.os.Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //... Some of your code where you get a list of you objects
    checkStates = new boolean[list.size()];
    // As an example, let's check some of them:
    checkStates[3] = true;
    checkStates[7] = true;
    //.. Something more
};

SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, list, R.layout.rowsecond, new String[] {"icon", "name"}, new int[] {R.id.image1, R.id.text1}) {
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        boxer = (CheckBox)v.findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
        boxer.setTag(position);
        boxer.setOnCheckedChangeListener(checkedChangeListener);
        boxer.setChecked(checkStates[position]);
        return v;
    }

    private final OnCheckedChangeListener checkedChangeListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(final CompoundButton buttonView, final boolean isChecked) {
            final Integer position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
            checkStates[position] = isChecked;
        }
    };
};
```

}

Don't forget to call yourAdapterInstance.notifyDataSetChanged() if you are trying to update checkboxes states from outside of checkedChangeListener and after initial onCreate() method;